# how to recursive load n children in comment table when lazy loading and proxies is false?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, linq

I want to get all comment with navigation property with Linq query. I disabled lazy loading and proxies in my entities.

```
public partial class dbCommentEntities : DbContext
{
    public dbCommentEntities()
        : base("name=dbCommentEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    }
}
```

And my query code  for load from database is

```
 var queryTest = (from c in db.Comments
                         where c.ParentId == null
                         orderby c.CommentId descending
                         select new minicomment { 
                            Title = c.Title,
                            CommentId = c.CommentId, 
                            Comments1 = c.Comments1}).Skip(skip).Take(take);
```

Now, if I enable lazy loading and proxy in my `dbcontext` it is work fine for me. it means get all level navigation...

But this is disable or enable equal false it only load one level for me.

How to get all level navigation when lazy and proxy is false

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: i just give incorrect data without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  `Eager Loading`.

Good article about [**Eager Loading.**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

**What is Eager Loading?**

> When using Eager Loading, the related entities are loaded along with
>   your target entity set.You use an Include statement in your query to
>   indicate which related entities you want to bring in.

An example :

```
 return (from owner in Catalog.Owners
                        where owner.Key == ownerKey
                         select owner)
                        .Include(o => o.Credits)
                        .Include(o => o.Provider)
```

Comment: include method load all records. it is no good for performance. i need a algoritm for search in table. for example i want 5 comment with nmulti level navigation. and i use page list. it have skip and take for select and limite recordes for load.